# When I use ZSH, how do I set PATH in /etc/profile.d?

Tags: environment-variables, zsh

I'm using `zsh` as my shell, and I'm trying to configure my environment.

I usually define my `$JAVA_HOME` variable by creating a file:

```
/etc/profile.d/java.sh
```

with the following content

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

then I logout and back in, and it all works, but for some reason the `PATH` variable is not set. It recognizes `JAVA_HOME`, but not the new `PATH`, see this terminal snippet:

```
~  echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05
~  echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

and I confirmed it by trying to run a command form the jvm

```
~  java -version
zsh: command not found: java
```

the `PATH` doesn't include the `$JAVA_HOME` as it should. is there something else I should check?

I have checked that if I run:

```
source /etc/profile.d/java.sh
```

it all runs correctly and my variables get set as they should, but shouldn't the scripts in `/etc/profile.d` run automatically?

Comment: Have you tried editing `~/.profile` and placing the variables there instead? It may be that `PATH` is being overwritten elsewhere in `/etc/profile.d/`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From my point of view, the best way is to add the following lines at the `~/.zshrc` file (if you don't already have it, then create it):

```
if [ -d "/path/to/jdk" ] ; then
    export PATH="/path/to/jdk/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Then restart your `zsh`, or just run `source ~/.zshrc` and then your PATH should be exactly as you wish.

Or, if you want to make the change to be system-wide, then add the previous code to the end of `/etc/zsh/zshenv` file.

But in any case do not use `/etc/profile.d` to automatically run scripts in `zsh`. This directory is useful only for the `bash` shell, not `zsh` as in your case. To understand this, open `/etc/profile` file, which is a [**bash** initialization file](http://linux.die.net/Bash-Beginners-Guide/sect_03_01.html) and in no case a [**zsh** initialization file](http://zshwiki.org/home/config/files), and you will see somewhere at the end of the file:

```
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

So, your scripts from `/etc/profile.d` directory will automatically run in `zsh` only if you add the previous code in a zsh initialization file, like `/etc/zsh/zprofile` for example, or source `/etc/profile` in `/etc/zsh/zprofile` file.

Comment: Perhaps `~/.zprofile` might be better than `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: If there is a /etc/profile.d then all scripts in there are run anyway regardless of zsh. Or they are on debian.

Comment: Your link to a zsh initialisation file is dead.

Comment: @RichieHH I'm on zsh and there are scripts in /etc/profile.d which aren't run, despite having the right permissions.

Answer (score 4):

I find that placing everything in one `.zshenv` file quickly becomes hard to manage. I recommend installing [oh-my-sh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) and then placing various customizations (env vars, functions) to the `.oh-my-sh/custom/` directory as separate `.zsh` files.

I also discovered that this approach works flawlessly when ssh'ing into machine when modifying env variables such as `PATH`. Also it works really nice together with [vcsh](https://github.com/RichiH/vcsh) for keeping customizations backed up and in sync.

Comment: Using oh my zsh framework, where would you put a variable with an ip adress (remote server) to use for ssh access? I need the ip for git and a login script to the server.

Comment: Hm. Not quite sure what you mean. I would put the config like ip addresses and usernames for ssh to `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: I personally prefer this approach to the accepted answer as I like the advantage of using vcsh and the "custom" folder for ZSH is an ideal place for stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

Since `JAVA_HOME` is set, you have confirmed that those scripts are sourced automatically, haven't you?

The only logical explanation is that `PATH` is set later on somehow. It should be originally set by PAM which reads `/etc/environment`, and as far as I know that happens before `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` files are sourced. Possibly zsh works different compared to bash in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue locally after running updates. Looks like the root issue is Drush doesn't know where to find a legit copy of php that includes pdo. Fortunately it supports stashing this path in an environment variable, so I did this on the commandline:

```
export DRUSH_PHP="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.39/bin/php"
```

That fixed the issue so I edited .zshrc and added that to the file, problem solved.

Comment: So, you're suggesting that `.zshrc` be used, the same as [the top answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/476435/158442)?